# Download a file from ftp using ftplib

Tags: python, ftplib

I am looking for a specific file within a folder on FTP. There are several folders and my code loops through each folder to find the file. Once, I find the file I would like to download it.

```
import ftplib
   import os, sys, os.path

    ftp = ftplib.FTP("xxxxxxxx")
    ftp.login("dbaxyz", "password123")


    files = []  




try:
    files = ftp.nlst()
except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
    if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
        print "No files in this directory"
    else:
        raise


for f in files:
    filess = [],
    filess=ftp.nlst(f)
    for i in filess:  
        if len(i)==34 and i[8:11]=="ACO" and i[12:17]=="CCLF9" and i[3:7]=="1263"  :
            print i
            local_filename = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\zubair.zahiruddin\\Desktop\\test', i)
            file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ i, file.write)


            file.close()

ftp.close()



#ftp.quit()
```

However, I get an error: perm file not found.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp.py", line 28, in <module>
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ i, file.write)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 414, in retrbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 339, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 249, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 224, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 The system cannot find the file specified.
```

PS C:\Users\zubair.zahiruddin\Desktop\test>

Comment: please post the exact and full error message including line numbers

Comment: can you `print i` just before `retrbinary()`?

Comment: yes , its printing                   P.A1263.ACO.CCLF9.D121121.T0940365
P.A1263.ACO.CCLF9.D121121.T0940365
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp.py", line 29, in <module>
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ i, file.write)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 414, in retrbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 249, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 224, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: could it be confused with a space in the filename?  Does FTP only support short filenames?

Comment: are there any whitespaces? please print some delimiters around the string like `print '#%s#' % i`